# Proof of the canonical commutator relationship from $\hat{p}=-i\hbar \nabla$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

Given that $\hat{r} \psi = r\psi$ where $r$ is the position of a quantum particle, and where $\hat{p}=-i\hbar \nabla$, the notes I have simply state that

$$[\hat{r}_i, \hat{p}_j] = i\hbar \delta_{ij}$$
where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta.
Is there a proof of this from the fundamental results i.e. the definitions of these operators?
I am also not sure what the deal with the subscripts $i, j$ is. Are they the $i,j$th particle in the system?
What I did seems stupid, but I want to know where I am going wrong:

so $$(\hat{r}_i\hat{p}_j - \hat{p}_j\hat{r}_i)\psi = i\hbar(r\cdot\nabla-\nabla\cdot r)\psi \\
=i\hbar((xe_x+ye_y+ze_z)\cdot(\psi_x e_x+\psi_y e_y+\psi_z e_z)-((x\psi)_x+(y\psi)_y+(z\psi_z))) \\ 
=-3i\hbar (\psi)$$
Where I have said $r = xe_x+ye_y+ze_z$, and $\nabla = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}e_x + \frac{\partial }{\partial y}e_y + \frac{\partial }{\partial z}e_z$, where $e_i$ are standard cartesian unit vectors.

How does the definition of $\nabla$ change with the particle$j$, if at all it does?

I would appreciate any advice you have for me.

Comment: “Are they the $i$, $j$th particle in the system?” No. The indices label spatial dimensions, not particles. For example, $r_1$ is $x$.

Comment: There is no $\psi_x$, etc.

Comment: @G.Smith, quite literally your first comment solves the problem. Thank you!